# How would one determine the temperature needed such that hydrogen peroxide will start to decompose?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, temperature, decomposition

Hydrogen peroxide decomposes at room temperature and so I was wondering what temperature is sufficient for this decomposition to occur.

Can someone explain how we can determine this? (theoretically or experimentally - but to me it seems like it would be easier to determine experimentally)
I don't know if there is a technical word for this - maybe activation temperature?

I also googled the activation energy for the decomposition of hydrogen peroxide (without a catalyst) and it is around 75 kJ/mol which seems really high since it decomposes even at room temperature.

Comment: Ther Is no temperature above which it decomposes and below it does not. It is rather about an arbitrary choice of acceptable decomposition rate.

Comment: @Poutnik So H2O2 will decompose at any temperature greater than absolute zero, just very slowly at lower temperatures?

Answer (score 1):

The question can be reformulated to:

"At what T is the equation $\exp{\left(-\frac{E}{RT}\right)}=0$ true ?"

There is no temperature above which $\ce{H2O2}$ decomposes and below which it does not. It is rather about an arbitrary choice of acceptable decomposition rate.

It is similar to solvent evaporation. There is no temperature above which solvent evaporates and below which solvent does not evaporate. That includes frozen solvent.

At very low temperatures, $\ce{H2O2}$ is kinetically very stable, but thermodynamically still unstable. The kinetic stability can be so high you would not notice the decomposition.

E.g. Let assume the supposed the shelf life of a substance is 2 years. If T is temperature at/below which there is insignificant decomposition (product purpose dependent) after 2 years, there can be arbitrarily stated it is stable at/below T.

Comment: I was originally thinking about it with Gibbs energy of activation and setting that to 0 and solving for the temperature (which would be the temperature such that the reaction is barrierless). So something like this: $T = \frac{\Delta H}{\Delta S}$ in terms of activation. And then I was thinking this would give me the temperature when hydrogen peroxide will start decomposing without any additional energy needed (which is what we see when storing H2O2). This would in fact get me some temperature which I guess isnt what I think it is. Could you tell me where I am wrong in my reasoning?

Comment: From what you said I guess it is wrong to say that only a barrierless reaction results in decomposition without any extra energy. So if this is true, what does a barrierless reaction mean?

Comment: Well, the reaction is exothermic, so lowering the temperature shifts the equilibrium constant by the van't Hoff equation toward the decomposition.

Comment: Sorry I am just going to learn equilibrium stuff next in school so I dont know much about the equilibrium constant (or that equation), but are you saying that by lowering the temperature the reaction is more likely to proceed by decomposition than the reverse?

Comment: I was just wondering about what it means for Gibbs energy of activation to be 0 because I dont think I understood properly, I thought it meant that its 0 when the reaction no longer needs any energy input to proceed (activation energy is met) and so the temperature when $\Delta G = 0$, is the minimum temperature needed for the decomposition to occur but you were saying that H2O2 decomposes at any temperature, so I must have misunderstood something about the Gibbs energy of activation and what it means for a reaction to be "barrierless".

Comment: Keep in mind $\Delta G(T)=\Delta H(T)-T \cdot \Delta S(T)$. Its eventual zero value would mean K for the equilibrium with the activated complex is 1. For H2O2 case and lowering temperature, both rate constants for peroxide creation and decomposure decrease, but the former faster, so equilibrium constant shifts in favour of decomposure.